# What is the right way: “pour faire un cadeau” or “pour offrir un cadeau”?

Tags: sens, usage

What is the difference in meaning (or more meaningful) between :

> Pour faire un cadeau

and

> Pour offrir un cadeau

Answer (score 1):

On *offre un cadeau* à un proche, un ami, c'est du domaine de l'*offrande*, c'est-à-dire de la reconnaissance de l'autre au travers de l'objet que l'on transmet.

*Je te fais cadeau* de ce que tu me dois, de ton obligation de faire quelque chose pour moi : le *cadeau* n'est plus une offrande, mais un abandon d'une créance.

Si un commerçant *fait cadeau* de la TVA, il indique qu'il ne fera pas payer la TVA au client, il fait une *ristourne*, ce cadeau est un supplément à une transaction en cours.

Comment: Ok, thanks @cl-r, so if I understand correctly «faire un cadeau» is "doing a favour" to someone?

Comment: +1 Could not have explained it better!

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Je crois que votre expression est bonne : *doing a favour* ou "accorder une faveur" (soutenu) , "faire une fleur" (familier et oral, surtout employé dans les rapports commerciaux), "faire un cadeau" sont très proches et interchangeables selon les circonstances.

Comment: According to https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/faire-cadeau/ , "faire cadeau" can also mean "to give a gift" and it is a synonym of "offrir un cadeau". Ex: 
Mon copain m’a fait cadeau d’un vélo. Isn't that right?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista — D'après votre lien, "to let off easily" est le sens réel, si c'est moi qui donne le cadeau avec l'idée que j'ai quelque chose que je peux céder à quelqu'un sans que cela me coûte (je n'achète rien) alors que pour  "offrir un cadeau", il faut que j'y réfléchisse avant de l'acheter (ou je donne quelque chose que je possède qui a de l'importance pour moi). Du point de vue du receveur, les deux sont équivalents.